# Integral with four modified Bessel functions of the second kind of imaginary order

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions, integral-transforms

I've been trying to compute the following integral with no avail, does anyone have any ideas? All free constants are strictly positive. $K_\nu(x)$ is the usual modified Bessel function of the second kind, also known as Macdonald function.

$$
\int_0^\infty K_{i a_1}(b_1 x) K_{i a_2}(b_2 x) K_{i a_3}(b_3 x) K_{i a_4}(b_4 x)x\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Spontaneously, computing this exactly seems tedious but doable---rewrite the Bessel functions using a standard integral representation like $K_\alpha(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x \cosh t} \cosh(\alpha t) \, d t$. Gather up all the resulting $\cos$ terms (since the $\cosh(\alpha t)$ terms become cosines for purely imaginary orders $\alpha$), expand the fourfold product of cosines into a sum of (I guess) eight cosine terms, split into eight integrals of roughly the shape $\int \int e^{-c_1 x \cosh t} \cos(c_2 t) x \, d t \, d x$.

Comment: If all you care about is the rough size in terms of the constants, stationary phase method would be the standard tool to attack this.

Comment: For what it's worth, for a product of two $K$-Bessel functions with the same order, this is in Gradstheyn-Ryzhik, 6.521.3. Namely $\int_0^\infty x K_\nu(a x) K_\nu(b x) \, d x = \frac{\pi (a b)^{-\nu} (a^{2 \nu} - b^{2 \nu})}{2 \sin(\nu\pi) (a^2 - b^2)}$ (under some suitable conditions on the real parts of $\nu$ and $a+b$).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, but when I tried the brute force method the whole problem is that each bessel will have a different $t$ so you actually get a bunch of integrals that look like $\int e^{-x(b_1 \cosh t_1+b_2 \cosh t_2+...)} \cos(a_1 t_1 -a_2 t_2+...)$. I can do the $x$ integral no problem but right after the first $t$ integral it gets impossibly complicated